# Non-constant Torque issue in FOC algorithm (Simulink)

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-deployment

I am trying to develop a FOC algorithm in Simulink (see image attached) but I am having strange results in my simulation. My torque is not constant when it should instead varying periodically (see image attached) when it should be constant at 2 Nm. Also, the scope for my q-axis current probe is giving me a strange graph (see image attached) I can't even make sense of. Please if anyone could help me I would appreciate it since I have no clue what is going on. I don't know if it could be due to the values of my PI regulator. But I already tried all sorts of values and have no idea what else I can do. Please could someone help me out?

P.S. Simulink file can be downloaded from my OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AokIrMv_d8kz3BMaImhVY_guP_N-?e=3H9HRJ

[image: Simulink FOC Algorithm]

[image: Torque_Scope_Screenshot]

[image: Quadrature Current Screenshot]

Comment: This question is not in the scope of stackoverflow anymore, its clearly an engineering question you should discuss with your supervisor.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I am trying to develop a FOC algorithm for me to be able to apply the prinicples ad simulate them. From there on I could implement FOC as a torque controller in future motor control projects and that is why I am asking here. Does anyone know what could be going on in my simulation ?

Comment: "Does anyone know what could be going on in my simulation" - it is a valid question, but it is the wrong place. You could try at [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).